# Why does keyup not work with alphabet in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, events, keyup

I have a problem with input and keyup.

When I write number or enter or space btn it is works fine. and programm stoped on debugger in keyup function.

[write number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZkXB.png)

when i write alphabet it is not working.

[write alphabet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxieR.png)

Comment: Did u try 'change'?

Comment: @Zumm yes i tried. And it is work. But Users want to see changes in another inputs when they keyup text.when i use 'change'  the result is visible when click on another input or change focus

Comment: Could you include the relevant code? The native `keyup` event should be firing but if you're relying on propagation it's possible that something else is stopping it reaching the element with your listener. I would also suggest that you consider using the `input` event instead of `keyup` as it takes into account other forms of content manipulation, e.g. drag/drop and context-menu copy/paste.